# Xamarin switch between pages without loading new one

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I switch bewtween pages without loading a new page in Xamarin, so that when I make a change on a page and I load it again in the same session, I can see the change I made, but when I close the app and open it again the change is gone?

[image: **enter image description here**]

As you can see, when I go to the "Doel sport" page and I go back to the "Doel gewicht" page, the radio button is still selected. But when I then go back to "Doel sport" page, the radio button is not selected anymore (and the page loads two times, I don't know why?)

"Doel gwicht" page xaml:

```
<controls:AnimationPage
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FormsControls.Base;assembly=FormsControls.Base" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="TimeToSport.Views.GegevensGewichtDoel"
        xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons;assembly=Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms"
        Title="Doel gewicht">


<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Volgende" Clicked="Volgende_clicked">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="volgende.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                 Padding="10,30,0,0"  
                 Spacing="10">


        <syncfusion:SfRadioGroup x:Name="radioGroup">

            <Label Text="Wat is je doel m.b.t. gewicht?"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="17"/>
            <syncfusion:SfRadioButton x:Name="btn_Afvallen" Text="Afvallen" TextColor="Gray" StateChanged="RadioButton_StateChanged"/>
            <syncfusion:SfRadioButton x:Name="btn_OpGewichtBlijven" TextColor="Gray" Text="Op gewicht blijven" StateChanged="RadioButton_StateChanged"/>
            <syncfusion:SfRadioButton x:Name="btn_Aankomen" TextColor="Gray" Text="Aankomen" StateChanged="RadioButton_StateChanged"/>
        </syncfusion:SfRadioGroup>    
         </StackLayout>
     </ContentPage.Content>
 </controls:AnimationPage>
```

"Doel gwicht" page cs:

```
        void CreateRadioButtons()
    {
        SfRadioGroup radioGroup = new SfRadioGroup();
        SfRadioButton btn_Afvallen = new SfRadioButton();
        btn_Afvallen.IsChecked = false;
        btn_Afvallen.Text = "Afvallen";
        btn_Afvallen.StateChanged += RadioButton_StateChanged;
        SfRadioButton btn_OpGewichtBlijven = new SfRadioButton();
        btn_OpGewichtBlijven.Text = "Op gewicht blijven";
        btn_OpGewichtBlijven.StateChanged += RadioButton_StateChanged;
        SfRadioButton btn_Aankomen = new SfRadioButton();
        btn_Aankomen.Text = "Aankomen";
        btn_Aankomen.StateChanged += RadioButton_StateChanged;
        radioGroup.Children.Add(btn_Afvallen);
        radioGroup.Children.Add(btn_OpGewichtBlijven);
        radioGroup.Children.Add(btn_Aankomen);
    }

    private void RadioButton_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new GegevensSportDoel());
    }

    void Volgende_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new GegevensSportDoel());
    }
```

"Doel Sport" page xaml:

```
<controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>
    <controls:PushPageAnimation Duration="Medium" Subtype="FromRight" />
</controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Klaar" Clicked="Klaar_clicked">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="volgende.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                 Padding="10,30,0,0"  
                 Spacing="10">


        <syncfusion:SfRadioGroup x:Name="radioGroup">

            <Label Text="Wat is je doel m.b.t. sport?"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="17"/>
            <syncfusion:SfRadioButton x:Name="btn_SterkerWorden" Text="Afvallen" TextColor="Gray" />
            <syncfusion:SfRadioButton x:Name="btn_ConditieOpbouwen" TextColor="Gray" Text="Op gewicht blijven" />
            <syncfusion:SfRadioButton x:Name="btn_GeenVanBeide" TextColor="Gray" Text="Aankomen"/>
        </syncfusion:SfRadioGroup>


         </StackLayout>
     </ContentPage.Content>
 </controls:AnimationPage>
```

"Doel Sport" page cs:

```
    void CreateRadioButtons()
    {
        SfRadioGroup radioGroup = new SfRadioGroup();
        SfRadioButton btn_Afvallen = new SfRadioButton();
        btn_Afvallen.IsChecked = false;
        btn_Afvallen.Text = "Afvallen";
        SfRadioButton btn_OpGewichtBlijven = new SfRadioButton();
        btn_OpGewichtBlijven.Text = "Op gewicht blijven";
        SfRadioButton btn_Aankomen = new SfRadioButton();
        btn_Aankomen.Text = "Aankomen";
        radioGroup.Children.Add(btn_Afvallen);
        radioGroup.Children.Add(btn_OpGewichtBlijven);
        radioGroup.Children.Add(btn_Aankomen);
    }

    void Klaar_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ItemsPage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply need to maintain a reference to the new Page object instead of creating a new one every time

```
ItemsPage newPage = null;

void Klaar_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (newPage == null) {
      newPage = new ItemsPage()
    }

    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(newPage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I used the following code https://pastebin.com/qbEAjMS5/. When I click on a button on the first page, then go to the second page, then go back and then click on another button (so one is selected then), it crashes and it gives me the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Page must not already have a parent.` Why is that?

Comment: you probably need to save the ref to the Nav page instead of wrapping the existing ItemPage in a new nav page

Comment: Forgot to mention that the error comes from line 10 of the pastebin file, so your solution didn't unfortunately not work.

Comment: I've used this technique many times, it should work.  Unless you are trying to push the same instance of the page before it has been removed from the stack.

Comment: Yes, but the error doesn't come from `App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(newPage);` but from `Navigation.PushAsync(gegevensSportDoel);`, so I don't really understand what you mean that I have to change?

Comment: Finally fixed it by doing this `if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 0 || Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(GegevensSportDoel))
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(gegevensSportDoel);
            }` Thanks for your answer, it partially worked for me.